# Extracting <br> records from html parsed data using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags, html-parsing

I have online text data like this:

```
    plain_text= "<a href="/url?q=https://www.aarnoldmovingcompany.com/contact-us/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwCgAMAA&amp;usg=AOvVaw1pasRFOwk">
        </b> Moving Louisville - Headquarters.<br>
commercial moving services nationwide. Visit our website today to learn more!<br><div class="osl">
<br>
         5200 Interchange Way Louisville, KY 40229.<br>
         ... <b> A. Arnold</b>"
```

I am trying to extract all `<br>` tags from this text, so output will look like:

```
commercial moving services nationwide. Visit our website today to learn more

5200 Interchange Way Louisville, KY 40229.
```

This doesn't work for me:

```
 soup=BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"lxml")
 out=soup.find_all('br')
```

It throws me:

```
[<br/>,
 <br/>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next_sibling, check the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """<a href="/url?q=https://www.aarnoldmovingcompany.com/contact-us/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwCgAMAA&amp;usg=AOvVaw1pasRFOwk">
        </b> Moving Louisville - Headquarters.<br>
commercial moving services nationwide. Visit our website today to learn more!<br><div class="osl">
<br>
         5200 Interchange Way Louisville, KY 40229.<br>
         ... <b> A. Arnold</b>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'lxml')
name = soup.br.next_sibling
address = name.next.next.text.strip()
print(name, '\n', address)
```

Output

```
 commercial moving services nationwide. Visit our website today to learn more!
 5200 Interchange Way Louisville, KY 40229.
         ...  A. Arnold
```

Comment: what if there are multiple br tags and I want to return all of them?

Comment: use find_all if there are multiple br tags

Comment: find_all('br.next_sibling')?